# How to express this query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table called Reporting with following columns

```
OutletId CampaignId    ItemId  Qty  
10          1          Item1   12    
10          1          Item2   13    
10          1          Item3   14    
20          2          Item4   10    
20          2          Item5   11    
20          2          Item6   12    
20          2          Item7   8
```

Now I want to retrieve the data in this format
when user select campaignId =1

```
OutletId   CampaignId  Item1  Item2   Item3  
10            1         12     13       14
```

when user select CampaignId=2

```
OutletId   CampaignId Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7   
20            2         10    11   12    8
```

Here Items for campaign are not fixed

Comment: you should rethink the design since this won't be possible (dynamic count of columns) and is very inefficient...

Comment: @Yahia: Pivoting is not entirely impossible, but you're right. Maybe rethinking the design is a better option

Comment: @LukasEder you are right Pivoting is an option... though not really efficient...

Comment: @Yahia please check my answer and i think u will change ur decision...

Comment: @Tareq as I said in my last comment - it is possible, but inefficient (performance etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is efficient in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT OutletId, CampaignId, ItemId, Qty
FROM Reporting) AS p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR ItemId IN (SELECT ItemId FROM Reporting WHERE campaignId =1) 
) as pvt
```

`Comment: Here campaignId =1 or campaignId =2 or campaignId =... whatever u want`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT OutletId, CampaignId,ItemId, Qty
FROM test) AS p
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR ItemId IN (Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4)
) as pvt
```

But obviously, as commented before is not very efficient because you don't always know the Items... you either redesign your table or if using PIVOT you can build a dynamic sql building pivot items previously.